# VBAで<開く>ダイアログボックスから選択したファイルのパスを取得するには

Tags: macos, vba, excel

VBAで<開く>ダイアログボックスから選択したファイルのパスを取得する方法についての質問です。

VBAで<開く>ダイアログボックスからファイルを選択は、下記のように実現しました。

```
 strFileName = MacScript("Choose File")
```

ファイルパスを取得しようとしたのですが、構文エラーとなり、パスが取得できません。

```
 MsgBox strFileName
 intFF = FreeFile
 Open strFileName For Input As #intFF　　←ここでエラー
```

strFileNameをウォッチ式で確認すると、下記のようになりました。

[image: strFileName]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA自体でもファイル選択ダイアログを出す事ができますので以下の様にすれば取得することができます。
Falseが返った場合、ダイアログでキャンセルされています。

```vb
Dim strFilename As Variant
Dim intFF As Integer

strFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename
Debug.Print strFilename

if strFilename = False then Exit Sub

intFF = FreeFile
Open strFilename For Input As #intFF
Input #intFF, strLine
Debug.Print strLine
Close #intFF
```

AppleScriptを利用するのであれば、`as text` か `as string` を指定するとOpenでも使用できる形式で結果を取得する事ができます。
キャンセルされた場合エラーとなるので、AppleScript側で対処するか、VBAで On Error を利用して対処してください。

```vb
Err.Clear
On Error Resume Next

strFilename = MacScript("choose file  as String")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
End If

Debug.Print strFilename

intFF = FreeFile
Open strFilename For Input As #intFF
Input #intFF, strLine
Debug.Print strLine
Close #intFF
```

なお、Debug.Print の結果は `表示` メニューから `イミディエイトウィンドウ` で開ける、イミディエイトウィンドウ上で確認できます。